# I need help drawing sunrays, glimmers, bursts, sparkles, etc in C

Tags: image, graphics, drawing, photoshop

I am in the process of learning how to create a lens flare application. I've got most of the basic components figured out and now I'm moving on to the more complicated ones such as the glimmers / glints / spikeball as seen here: http://wiki.nuaj.net/images/e/e1/OpticalFlaresLensObjects.png

Or these: http://ak3.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1996229/preview/stock-footage-blue-flare-rotate.jpg

Some have suggested creating particles that emanate outwards from the center while fading out and either increasing or decreasing in size but I've tried this and there are just too many nested loops which makes performance awful.

Someone else suggested drawing a circular gradient from center white to radius black and using some algorithms to lighten and darken areas thus producing rays.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm really stuck on this one.

I am using a limited compiler that is similar to C but I don't have any access to antialiasing, predefined shapes, etc. Everything has to be hand-coded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would create large circle selections, then use a radial gradient. Each side of the gradient is white, but one side has 100% alpha and the other 0%. Once you have used the gradient tool to draw that gradient inside the circle. Deselect it and use the transform tool to Skew or in a sense smash it. Then duplicate it several times and turn each one creating a spiral or circle holding Ctrl to constrain when needed. Then once those several layers are in the rotation or design that you want. Group them in a folder and then you can further effect them all at once with another transform or skew. WHen you use these real smal, they are like little stars. But you can do many different things when creating each one to make them different. Like making each one lower in opacity than the last etc...

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply, Eric. But this shows how to make a texture in an app like Photoshop and I know how to do all that. It's easy. I'm talking about generating these using code. I'm looking for helpful algorithms that may accomplish something similar to the examples I posted. Generating in realtime using code is of course much more difficult to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found a few examples of how to do lens-flare 'via code'. Ideally you'd want to do this as a `post-process` - meaning after you're done with your regular render, you process the image further.

Fragment shaders are apt for this step. The easiest version I found is [this one](http://john-chapman-graphics.blogspot.com/2013/02/pseudo-lens-flare.html). The basic idea is to

1. Identify really bright spots in your image and potentially down sample it.
2. Shoot rays from the fragment to the center of the image and sample some pixels along the way.
3. Accumalate the samples and apply further processing - chromatic distortion etc - on it.

And you get a whole range of options to play with.

Another more common alternative seems to be

1. Have a set of basic images (circles, hexes) and render them as a bunch of bright objects, along the path from the camera to the light(s).
2. Composite this image on top of the regular render of you scene.

The problem is in determining when to turn on lens flare, since it is dependant on whether a light is visible/occluded from a camera. [GPU Gems](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch29.html) comes to rescue, with better options.

A more serious, physically based implementation is listed [in this paper](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~hullin/projects/lensflareRendering/pdf/flare.pdf). This is a real-time version of making lens-flares, but you need a hardware that can support *both vertex and geometry shaders*.